# Promise.resolve inside of async.series()

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, module.exports

I am exporting a function which returns a promise. When I return at the top this function
the promise resolves as expected. 
But if I return the promise in the final function (or any of the functions in the series),
the promise does not resolve or work at all.

```
module.exports = function() {

  //- - - - - - - -- - - - -
  //If i resolve the promise here it works as expected
  return Promise.resolve();
  //- - - - - - - -- - - - -

  async.series({
    ....
    someFunction: function(cb){
     cb();
    },
    ....
  }, function(err, results) {
    //- - - - - - - -- - - - -
    //but if I resolve the promise here it doesn't work
    return Promise.resolve();
    //- - - - - - - -- - - - -
  });

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "... I resolve the promise here ..." - no you return a resolved Promise from a callback function passed to `async.series()`, which is dramatically different from returning Promise from the exported function. 

As I understand it, `async.series()` returns Promise if no callback is passed. Therefore try omitting the callback and write `return async.series(...)`. May not be the whole answer but should get you started.

Comment: If you wish to manipulate the series results (or invoke side effects), then you can write `return async.series(...).then(results => { return someManipulationOf(results) });`

Comment: Hmm.. I just tried both of the above you mentioned, still no luck... I'm using a node package for queuing tasks called 'bull' which is what is requiring this promise to be returned. I wonder if it maybe has anything to do with that.

Comment: Try https://github.com/baryon/named-promise-task